# Is there really no find_all_indices

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have

```
ary = ['aa', 'b', 'cba', 'd', 'df']
```

and want to find the indices of all the elements that match `/a/`. It is easy to get the relevant values, using

```
ary.find_all { |v| v =~ /a/ }
=> ["aa", "cba"]
```

and what I want to write is

```
ary.find_all_indices { |v| v =~ /a/ }
```

but there is no such thing. All I can come up with is

```
(0..ary.size-1).find_all { |i| ary[i] =~ /a/ }
=> [0, 2]
```

Can anyone help me to find something better?

Comment: `ary.each.with_index.select { |v, idx| v =~ /a/ }.map{|v, i| i}`

Comment: Your implementation is perfectly sane. You can monkey patch the Enumerable with your utility method if want.

Comment: Slightly better than your code would be `0.upto(ary.size - 1).select { ... }` or `(0...ary.size).select { ... }`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I think you mean `each_with_index`

Comment: The docs for 1.9.3 core say about `each_with_index` *"Given arguments are passed through to each()."* but it takes no parameters. Is this a doc bug? If not then how does it apply? I'll start a new question if this isn't just my naïveté.

Comment: @Borodin: both ways work

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Sorry, I looked at `Array` and `Enumerable` but not `Enumerator`. I didn't think there was a `with_index` method.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Please submit your comment as a solution. Your code is being discussed and will get an upvote at least from me.

Comment: @Borodin: nah, it's the slowest one.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no `find_all_indices`, but you're free to combine `each_index` and `find_all`:

```
ary.each_index.find_all{|i| ary[i] =~ /a/}
# => [0, 2]
```

Comment: I really wanted a DRY solution that avoided reindexing `ary` in teh block, but it looks like this is the best Ruby has to offer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's always interested to see what runs fastest:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 10_000
ARY = ('aa' .. 'zz').to_a 
DIVIDER = '-' * 40

def sergio_tulentsev(ary)
  ary.each.with_index.select { |v, idx| v =~ /a/ }.map{|v, i| i}
end

def priti(ary)
  (0..ary.size - 1).each_with_object([]) { |v,ob| ob << v if ary[v].include? 'a'}
end

def darshan_computing(ary)
  ary.each_index.find_all{|i| ary[i] =~ /a/}
end

puts "Ruby version: #{`ruby -v`}"
puts DIVIDER
puts 'Sergio Tulentsev:  ' + sergio_tulentsev(ARY).join(',')
puts 'Priti:             ' + priti(ARY).join(',')
puts 'Darshan Computing: ' + darshan_computing(ARY).join(',')
puts DIVIDER

2.times do
  Benchmark.bm(17) do |b|

    b.report('Sergio Tulentsev')  { N.times { sergio_tulentsev(ARY) }}
    b.report('Priti')             { N.times { priti(ARY) }}
    b.report('Darshan Computing') { N.times { darshan_computing(ARY) }}

  end
end
```

Which outputs:

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

```
----------------------------------------
Sergio Tulentsev:  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Priti:             0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Darshan Computing: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
----------------------------------------
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev    4.270000   0.000000   4.270000 (  4.272826)
Priti               2.020000   0.010000   2.030000 (  2.025979)
Darshan Computing   3.690000   0.010000   3.700000 (  3.704790)
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev    4.240000   0.010000   4.250000 (  4.239833)
Priti               2.000000   0.000000   2.000000 (  2.001301)
Darshan Computing   3.700000   0.020000   3.720000 (  3.718807)
```

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

```
----------------------------------------
Sergio Tulentsev:  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Priti:             0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Darshan Computing: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
----------------------------------------
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev    4.520000   0.010000   4.530000 (  4.529948)
Priti               2.150000   0.000000   2.150000 (  2.153721)
Darshan Computing   3.370000   0.010000   3.380000 (  3.390537)
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev    4.560000   0.010000   4.570000 (  4.580625)
Priti               2.230000   0.010000   2.240000 (  2.228714)
Darshan Computing   3.560000   0.000000   3.560000 (  3.567562)
```

Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

```
----------------------------------------
Sergio Tulentsev:  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Priti:             0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Darshan Computing: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
----------------------------------------
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev   13.770000   0.020000  13.790000 ( 13.801769)
Priti               7.760000   0.010000   7.770000 (  7.774238)
Darshan Computing   8.720000   0.020000   8.740000 (  8.743842)
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev   12.930000   0.010000  12.940000 ( 12.948077)
Priti               7.890000   0.010000   7.900000 (  7.898609)
Darshan Computing   8.450000   0.010000   8.460000 (  8.464012)
```

These values surprised me so I ran it twice at different times, and they were consistent.

Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

```
----------------------------------------
Sergio Tulentsev:  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Priti:             0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Darshan Computing: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
----------------------------------------
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev    4.890000   0.010000   4.900000 (  4.899299)
Priti               2.110000   0.000000   2.110000 (  2.115395)
Darshan Computing   3.710000   0.010000   3.720000 (  3.727729)
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev    4.960000   0.020000   4.980000 (  4.971293)
Priti               2.170000   0.000000   2.170000 (  2.182052)
Darshan Computing   3.620000   0.010000   3.630000 (  3.623773)
```

My machine is busy running other stuff right now, so the values might be a bit slower than someone else's machine, especially a newer one, but it's the relative values that are important.

---

Ruby v2.0-p0 shows a lot slower results. Dunno why. Here's results, with an algorithm I wrote that reduces the times. I think Priti's code is overall the best, though I think it could probably be twiddled and sped up a bit more.

```
def tinman2(ary)
  idxes = []
  ary.size.times { |idx| (idxes << idx) if (ary[idx] =~ /a/) }
  idxes
end

Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
----------------------------------------
Sergio Tulentsev:  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Priti:             0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Darshan Computing: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Tinman2:           0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
----------------------------------------
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev   11.600000   0.050000  11.650000 ( 11.646425)
Priti               6.880000   0.020000   6.900000 (  6.903026)
Darshan Computing   7.560000   0.000000   7.560000 (  7.562145)
TheTinMan2          6.690000   0.000000   6.690000 (  6.695731)
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev   11.590000   0.010000  11.600000 ( 11.593051)
Priti               6.880000   0.000000   6.880000 (  6.889174)
Darshan Computing   7.580000   0.000000   7.580000 (  7.573390)
TheTinMan2          6.600000   0.000000   6.600000 (  6.607929)
                        user     system      total        real
Sergio Tulentsev   11.580000   0.010000  11.590000 ( 11.582659)
Priti               6.880000   0.000000   6.880000 (  6.878172)
Darshan Computing   7.590000   0.000000   7.590000 (  7.591342)
TheTinMan2          6.590000   0.000000   6.590000 (  6.598353)
```

---

Borodin asked to have his algorithm added. I added another one using `include` also.

```
def tinman6(ary)
  idxes = []
  ary.size.times { |idx| (idxes << idx) if (ary[idx].include?('a')) }
  idxes
end

def borodin(ary)
  ary.each_index.find_all { |i| ary[i].include? 'a' }
end
```

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

```
----------------------------------------
Priti:   0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Tinman2: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Tinman6: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Borodin: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
----------------------------------------
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               1.880000   0.000000   1.880000 (  1.874891)
TheTinMan2          3.330000   0.000000   3.330000 (  3.337149)
TheTinMan6          1.660000   0.000000   1.660000 (  1.658698)
Borodin             1.740000   0.000000   1.740000 (  1.738520)
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               1.870000   0.000000   1.870000 (  1.872923)
TheTinMan2          3.320000   0.000000   3.320000 (  3.314796)
TheTinMan6          1.650000   0.000000   1.650000 (  1.650655)
Borodin             1.730000   0.000000   1.730000 (  1.732083)
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               1.870000   0.000000   1.870000 (  1.871353)
TheTinMan2          3.330000   0.000000   3.330000 (  3.332134)
TheTinMan6          1.650000   0.000000   1.650000 (  1.651290)
Borodin             1.730000   0.000000   1.730000 (  1.731993)
```

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

```
----------------------------------------
Priti:   0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Tinman2: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Tinman6: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Borodin: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
----------------------------------------
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               1.840000   0.000000   1.840000 (  1.833698)
TheTinMan2          3.090000   0.000000   3.090000 (  3.095056)
TheTinMan6          1.680000   0.000000   1.680000 (  1.676831)
Borodin             1.760000   0.000000   1.760000 (  1.766091)
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               1.840000   0.000000   1.840000 (  1.834253)
TheTinMan2          3.100000   0.000000   3.100000 (  3.102027)
TheTinMan6          1.720000   0.000000   1.720000 (  1.726131)
Borodin             1.780000   0.000000   1.780000 (  1.772062)
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               1.830000   0.000000   1.830000 (  1.833505)
TheTinMan2          3.110000   0.000000   3.110000 (  3.107236)
TheTinMan6          1.670000   0.000000   1.670000 (  1.677120)
Borodin             1.770000   0.000000   1.770000 (  1.763458)
```

Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

```
----------------------------------------
Priti:   0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Tinman2: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Tinman6: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Borodin: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
----------------------------------------
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               6.860000   0.030000   6.890000 (  6.891947)
TheTinMan2          6.680000   0.030000   6.710000 (  6.705629)
TheTinMan6          6.170000   0.000000   6.170000 (  6.175578)
Borodin             7.060000   0.000000   7.060000 (  7.058933)
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               6.820000   0.000000   6.820000 (  6.828020)
TheTinMan2          6.600000   0.000000   6.600000 (  6.600167)
TheTinMan6          6.050000   0.010000   6.060000 (  6.046283)
Borodin             6.870000   0.000000   6.870000 (  6.868911)
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               6.840000   0.000000   6.840000 (  6.847487)
TheTinMan2          6.600000   0.000000   6.600000 (  6.599859)
TheTinMan6          6.060000   0.000000   6.060000 (  6.058301)
Borodin             6.880000   0.000000   6.880000 (  6.886744)
```

Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

```
----------------------------------------
Priti:   0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Tinman2: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Tinman6: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
Borodin: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,546,572,598,624,650
----------------------------------------
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               1.900000   0.010000   1.910000 (  1.908870)
TheTinMan2          3.330000   0.020000   3.350000 (  3.353368)
TheTinMan6          1.800000   0.000000   1.800000 (  1.807138)
Borodin             1.780000   0.010000   1.790000 (  1.786934)
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               1.890000   0.010000   1.900000 (  1.896419)
TheTinMan2          3.320000   0.010000   3.330000 (  3.331743)
TheTinMan6          1.810000   0.010000   1.820000 (  1.821966)
Borodin             1.790000   0.000000   1.790000 (  1.784046)
                        user     system      total        real
Priti               1.880000   0.000000   1.880000 (  1.884283)
TheTinMan2          3.330000   0.000000   3.330000 (  3.332970)
TheTinMan6          1.810000   0.000000   1.810000 (  1.812595)
Borodin             1.780000   0.010000   1.790000 (  1.782502)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. If you add a version of Priti's solution that uses a regexp instead you will see that the efficiency comes from his choice of `include?`. If you replace the block with `{ |v,ob| ob << v if ary[v] =~ /a/}` then the performance slows dramatically to a result similar to the others. I am surprised by this as my experience with Perl tells me that a regular expression is preferable to a call to `index` every time. Of the others, Sergio's choice is about 20% slower than my own, which Darshan Computing's is just 1% faster.

Comment: For Ruby 2.0-p0 I have code that outruns Priti's but his is faster for all other versions. I'll append the code and a benchmark.

Comment: The fastest on my system is a variation of Darshan Computing's solution using Priti's `include?` instead of a regexp. Please add `ary.each_index.find_all { |i| ary[i].include? 'a' }` to your bench. It is better than twice as fast as Sergio' solution on 1.9.3.

Comment: I added yours. With 2.0-p195 you've got the lead. For all others I do. :-)

Comment: @Borodin, "as my experience with Perl tells me that a regular expression is preferable to a call to index every time." I did a bunch of benchmarks with Perl a couple years ago to look at the effects of anchored vs. unanchored patterns vs. literal searches. Literal was fastest *UNLESS* the search was anchored, which was then much faster. I didn't test the difference between using `^` vs. `\A` or `$` vs. `\Z` or `\z` but I know from tests done with Ruby's regex engine in the past, that `^` and `$` could be costly as the engine searched for embedded line-ends.

Comment: @theTinMan: Perl won't look for embedded line endings unless you apply the `/m` modifier. I would like to see your tests. For me, Perl 5 (16.2) code like `grep $ary[$_] =~ /a/, 0 .. $#ary` wins every time over `grep index($ary[$_], 'a') >= 0, 0 .. $#ary`.

Comment: As I said, the tests were several years ago. Perl 5.16.2 wasn't available then. It's changed a lot since I did them. My tests for anchors occurred in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

```
ary = ['aa', 'b', 'cba', 'd', 'df']
(0..ary.size - 1).each_with_object([]) { |v,ob| ob << v if ary[v].include? 'a'}
# => [0, 2]
```

Comment: That's a nice demo of how `each_with_object` works, but it's no more concise that mine, and I suspect no faster. Thanks.

Comment: Having benchmarked your code I am grateful to have discovered that yours is by far the fastest because of your use of `include?` instead of using a regexp. Thank you for alerting me to this.

Comment: @Borodin glad to hear that, I used `include?` with intention. :) But people might didn't like my one rather than you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution as well.

Doesn't bother with map, as that is done with the collection of the indices in the block.  Also, with map, I would have to remove the `nil` entries anyway, perhaps with `uniq` and then ignore the one occurrence of `nil`

```
indices = []
%w[here there are not many words with an a in them].each_with_index {|word, i| indices << i if word =~ /a/}
```

Hope it helps.